# react passing redux props to components

Tags: reactjs

Within this Avatar component, I want to set the state to match the props before it renders but the component only seems to update with the correct props in its render function.

eg.

main component gets data on its componentDidMount, passes that data to another component (Avatar), Avatar sets the state's data to match the passed data, UI renders with that data.

by default the redux store has avatar as avatar.png

```
class Account extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData();
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.props
        return(
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/avatar" exact={true} render={() => (<Avatar {...data} />)} />
            </Switch>
        )
    }
}

class Avatar extends React.Component { 

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        console.log('constructor', this.props)

        this.state = {}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount', this.props)
        // this.setState({ data: this.props.data })
    }

    render() {
        console.log('render', this.props)
        return null
    }

}


constructor {avatar: "avatar.png"}
test.js:62 render {avatar: "avatar.png"}
test.js:58 componentDidMount {avatar: "avatar.png"}
test.js:62 render {avatar: "something.png", other: "stuff"}
```

Comment: Might want to look into using redux-thunk

Comment: I'm using redux-thunk, perhaps incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're not waiting for the data from `fetchData` before rendering your `Avatar` component.
Since `componentDidMount` is only called once, on mount, it makes sense that you're only seeing your "correct" props in `render`.

Currently there is no way around this but in the future when [React Suspense](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6iR3Zk4oDY) comes out this will be a slight non-issue.